# Android Scrollview infinite scrolling

Tags: android, layout, scroll, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a problem with Android's `ScrollView`. I am facing infinite vertical scrolling. Even though I've run out of elements, I can keep scrolling through white space. I want the `ScrollView` to scroll down to the end of relative Layout. If you have any solution for this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:id="@+id/scroll1"

     >


<RelativeLayout  

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:background="@color/main_backgroundColor" >



      <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/Line"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

         <com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView
        android:id="@+id/mainGridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
           android:layout_below="@+id/Line"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp" />




        <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView_home"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />



</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse I don't know the structure of your project but why you don't use ListView with CWAC MergeAdapter? It can help you with infinite scroll.

Here is a link: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge